# PL/SQL Sum by hour

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have some data with start and stop date that I need to sum. I am not sure how to code for it.

Here are is the data I have to use:

```
STARTTIME,            STOPTIME,            EVENTCAPACITY
8/12/2009 1:15:00 PM, 8/12/2009 1:59:59 PM,     100

8/12/2009 2:00:00 PM, 8/12/2009 2:29:59 PM,     100

8/12/2009 2:30:00 PM, 8/12/2009 2:59:59 PM,      80

8/12/2009 3:00:00 PM, 8/12/2009 3:59:59 PM,      85
```

In this example I would need the sum from 1pm to 2pm, 2pm to 3pm and 3pm to 4pm

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Steve

Comment: The sum of the `eventcapacity`? And 1pm-2pm meaning what - the event starts and ends in that time? Or just any overlap at all?

Comment: Everything tzaman said, plus do the start_time and event_time ever span an hour eg 13:10 to 14:10 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about something like:

```
SELECT TRUNC(stoptime,'HH'), sum(eventcapacity) 
  FROM yourtable
 GROUP BY TRUNC(stoptime,'HH');
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I thought that would be much harder. I will become more familiar with TRUNC, I never used that.

Comment: Does this account for entries that span multiple hours? (as asked by APC above)

Comment: Several assumptions were made about the actual desired output, e.g., I assumed sums by hour by day, start time, etc., but the idea was to get the concept across.

Comment: You are welcome. I sometimes think a career could be made in understanding all the nuances of Oracle date processing ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You need a numbers table:

```
select sum(e.capacity), n.value from eventtable e
left outer join numbers n on n.value between
    extract(hours from e.starttime) and extract(hours from e.stoptime)
where n.value between 0 and 23
group by n.value
order by n.value
```

A numbers table has a single column (value) and is filled with integer values from 0 to 100 (or more) although in this case you only need 0 to 23.

```
create table number (
    value number(4) not null,
    primary key (value)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about exact PL/SQL syntax, but something like this should do it (though it's pretty unweildy):

```
select sum(capacity), case when to_char(starttime, 'HH') between '13' and '14'
                            and to_char(stoptime, 'HH') between '13' and '14'
                            then '1pm-2pm'
                      case when to_char(starttime, 'HH') between '14' and '15'
                            and to_char(stoptime, 'HH') between '14' and '15'
                            then '2pm-3pm'
                      (etc.) 
                      as timeslot
from eventtable
group by timeslot
```